# how to keep original unicode string in java?

Tags: java

I'm a new Java developer. In my project, i created a unicode string (Vietnamese Language), exam: " vượt ngưỡng 80%". But when i use the java project to insert this data into database, the data is transfomed to " v??t ng??ng 80%". Column of table of database was altered with UTF-8. And when i try insert with Sql Statemane using HeidiSql, the data was not transfomed. It mean the data in database is:"vượt ngưỡng 80%".
Please help me. 
Thank you for reading.
Here my class:

```
package com.wecommit.criticalService.createWarning;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.wecommit.criticalService.entity.TableSpace;
import com.wecommit.criticalService.entity.TableSpaceWarning;
import com.wecommit.criticalService.repository.TableSpaceWarningRepository;

@Service
public class TablespaceCreateWarning {

TableSpace tableSpace;
TableSpaceWarning tableSpaceWarning;
byte[] bytes = new byte[10];

String currientString;

List<TableSpaceWarning> listLastTableSpaceWarning;

@Autowired
TableSpaceWarningRepository tableSpaceWarningRepository;


public void setTablespaceCreateWarning
    (TableSpace tableSpace,
    TableSpaceWarning tableSpaceWarning)
{   
    this.currientString = "";
    this.tableSpace = tableSpace;
    this.tableSpaceWarning = tableSpaceWarning;
}

public void doTablespaceCreateWarning() {
    setflagWarning();
}

//all method
public void setflagWarning() {

    if (tableSpace.getUse_percentage() > 80) {
        tableSpaceWarning.setFull_flag(1);
        setReportWarningFlowTableSpace(this.currientString," vượt ngưỡng 80%");
    } 
}


public void setReportWarningFlowTableSpace(String currentWarning, String addedWarning) {

    currentWarning = currentWarning + "\r\n";
    currentWarning = currentWarning + tableSpace.getName() + addedWarning;
    currientString = currentWarning;
    tableSpaceWarning.setReport_warning(currentWarning);
}

public TableSpaceWarning getTableSpaceWarning() {
    return this.tableSpaceWarning;
}

}
```

Comment: @balusc knows everything about getting the right utf8 chars - see http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Comment: Hey,  Scary Wombat, thank you for showing me many infomations. When i read, i fixed eclipse to print unicode string. But in my project, i do not still fix above problem witch methods in topic. Can you help me.

Comment: Looks like your JDBC connection is not set to use  UTF-8.

Comment: Hey Sascha, i fixed this problem by your way. Thank you so much. Wish you a nice day.